# The implementation of Map implies that each key may contains only 1 value... But i need that 1 key could store <Any Big Number> values

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

For example... Adjacency list realiszation

```
public class Vertex {
    String name;
    boolean visited;
    public Vertex(String name) {
        this.name=name;
        visited=false;
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }
    public boolean equals(Object ob) {
        return hashCode()==ob.hashCode();
    }
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

The main class

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(System.out);
        Map<Vertex,Vertex> m=new HashMap();
        m.put(new Vertex("a"), new Vertex("b"));// a ---> b
        m.put(new Vertex("a"), new Vertex("c"));// a ---> c
        m.put(new Vertex("a"), new Vertex("d"));// a ---> d
        pw.println("All vertex from: ");
        for (Vertex vert_from:m.keySet()) {
            pw.print(vert_from+" ");
        }
        pw.println();
        pw.println("All vertices to: ");
        for (Vertex vert_to:m.values()) {
            pw.print(vert_to+" ");
        }
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

It outputs:
All vertex from:
 
a 
All vertices to: 
d 
But i need that "All vertices to: b c d" 
How can I fix that?

Comment: You are overriding the value against the Key named "a", you are looking for a list of values against your key

Comment: You need a Map with each value being a List or Vector, then put your existing values inside the lists.

Comment: BTW, your equals implementation is not correct. As it is now, it will return true for some names that are not equal. It should return `name.equals(ob.name)` instead. And it would not hurt to use some checking against incorrect types as well.

Answer (score 1):

A `Map` indeed stores a single value per key. You could, however, store a collection in value, say a `Set`:

```
Map<Vertex, Set<Vertex>> m = new HashMap<>();
Set<Vertex> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(new Vertex("b"));
set.add(new Vertex("c"));
set.add(new Vertex("d"));
m.add (new Vertex("a"), set);
```

Alternatively, you can use one of the common implementations of this concept, such as Apache Commons Collections' [`MultiValueMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiValueMap.html) or Guava's [`HashMultiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is called a "Multi Map".

If you are using Java 8 then this is quite neat, first you need a `Map<Vertex, Collection<Vertex>>`. I don't know what properties you need from the `Collection`, that you will have to investigate yourself.

As you have overridden `equals` and `hashCode` (incorrectly, but a valiant attempt), I will assume that you want to have the items unique by `name`. I will also assume that order matters, so `LinkedHashSet` seems a good choice.

```
final Map<Vertex, Collection<Vertex>> graph = new HashMap<>();
```

Now, to add an item to the `Map` we need to first ensure that the `Collection` for that key is not `null`. This is exactly what the new `Map.computeIfAbsent` comes in.

```
final Vertex a = new Vertex("a");
graph.computeIfAbsent(a, v -> new LinkedHashSet<>()).add(new Vertex("b"));
graph.computeIfAbsent(a, v -> new LinkedHashSet<>()).add(new Vertex("c"));
graph.computeIfAbsent(a, v -> new LinkedHashSet<>()).add(new Vertex("d"));
```

So what this does is, when inserting `a` into the `Map`, if the `Collection` for that key is `null`, computes a new value for it.

Now to get all values for a key:

```
Collection<Vertex> values = graph.get(a);
```

You could wrap the `Map<Vertex, Collection<Vertex>>` in some sort of `Graph` class to hide the implementation details and to have neater code:

```
class Graph {
    final Map<Vertex, Collection<Vertex>> graph = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(final Vertex key, final Vertex value) {
        graph.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new LinkedHashSet<>()).add(value);
    }

    public Collection<Vertex> get(final Vertex key) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(graph.get(key)).orElse(Collections.EMPTY_SET);
    }
}
```

This also deals with returning an empty collection instead of `null` if a key is not present in the `Map`. Depending on your use case you might also want to wrap the returned `Collection` with `Collections.unmodifiableCollection` to prevent unwanted modifications:

```
public Collection<Vertex> get(final Vertex key) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(graph.get(key))
            .map(Collections::unmodifiableCollection)
            .orElse(Collections.EMPTY_SET);
}
```

You could also use a Guava [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) if you aren't averse to external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Multimap for your problem, it could be written like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(System.out);
    ListMultimap<Vertex,Vertex> m= ArrayListMultimap.create();

    Vertex a = new Vertex("a"); // it's better to create each object once
    Vertex b = new Vertex("b");
    Vertex c = new Vertex("c");
    Vertex d = new Vertex("d");

    m.put(a,b);// a ---> b
    m.put(a,c);// a ---> c
    m.put(a,d);// a ---> d
    pw.println("All vertex from: ");
    for (Vertex vert_from:m.keySet()) { //exactly the same as in your code
        pw.print(vert_from+" ");
    }
    pw.println();
    pw.println("All vertices to: ");
    for (Vertex vert_to:m.values()) { //exactly the same as in your code
        pw.print(vert_to+" ");
    }
    pw.close();
}
```

To use Guava, just download the latest jar from [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and add it to your libraries.

---

**Explanation:**

By definition, each java Map has a single key and a single value.

However, you can use a Collection (like a List), or an Array for value. This way, your Map will be defined like that:

```
Map<Vertex, List<Vertex>> m = new HashMap<>();
```

Each time you want to add an element `value` to the list of vertex `key`, you can do it that way:

```
List<Vertex> list = m.get(key);
if (list == null) {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
}
list.add(value);
```

An easier way, is to use Guava's [Multimaps](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). It is the same as a Map, but the value is a Collection. So, an [ArrayListMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) is quite what I described above. The way to use it, though is much simpler:

```
ListMultimap<Vertex, Vertex> m = ArrayListMultimap.create();
m.put(key, value1);
m.put(key, value2); //adds value2 to the key, which also contains value1
....
```